# How to check the size of a JSON response?

Tags: javascript, json

Is there any way I can check the response size? Data property is a byte array which I am using to display an image. If the size is greater than 10 MB I need to show a popup.

```
{
  "Name": "sharon",
  "Date": "07\/14\/2004",
  "Data": "JVBERi0xLjINCg0KNC",
  "DocumentId":1540,
}
```

Also how can I check the type of my response, whether it's blob or something? Can I check the size of the blob I am getting? Maybe something like this:

```
var data = JSON.parse(this.responseData);
```

Comment: You can use `.length` attribute of the `Data` property. If it's greater than 1024^2 then show the popup.

Comment: u mean something like this.... this.responseData.length or this.responseData.data.length

Comment: Kevin: `this.responseData.data.length`

Comment: why not have the server return the size as another json property?

Comment: @DmitryBeransky, because browsers themselves interpret `.length` differently for new lines. The "incoming data" on that server is not necessarily on that server.  To be sure, run console.log() to show the value during your tests.

Answer (score 1):

You simply can use JavaScript `.length` for this, but do realize different browsers as well as servers will report different values since some interpretation of newlines can be 1 of 2  size values (byte-order).

Having said that, use a "loose" value that your sure contains the data you need, and not just the header response that has no value.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to look at the HTTP header for the AJAX response? (Assuming it is there, of course)

Comment: Use `.length` is assumed on a `success` event, which just implies that something was received, not necessarily the data.. *the meaty part*... you were expecting.

Answer (score 0):

You can slurp the incoming response into one line and remove all unnecessary white-space.

```
var JSON = '{\r\n' +
'   "Name": "sharon",\r\n' +
'   "Date": "07\/14\/2004",\r\n' +
'   "Data": "JVBERi0xLjINCg0KNC",\r\n' +
'   "DocumentId":1540,\r\n' +
'}';
alert(JSON);
alert(JSON.length); // 101

var newJSON = slurp(JSON);
alert(newJSON);
alert(newJSON.length); // 91

function slurp(str) {
  str = str.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
  str = str.replace(/(\s+|\t)/gm,' ');
  return str;
}
```

Comment: In Perl, slurping means to strip all line feeds and carriage returns.